# how to reset stopImmediatePropagation

Tags: jquery, onchange, mousedown, kendo-grid

I'm stuck here and not able to proceed further. Any help/ pointer will be appreciated.

I've a Kendo grid and I'm extending a function on the grid so that before change event is fired, I'm binding the mousedown event to get confirmation from the user. Only upon receiving a positive confirmation, change event should be fired. On negative confimation, I'm using 'stopImmediatePropagation' which serves the purpose.

```
$("#KendoGrid").extendedFunction();
```

The extended function is defined as below:

```
$.fn.extendedFunction= function () {
    var $grid = $(this);
    var $kGrid = $grid.data("kendoGrid");

    if (!$kGrid) {
        return this;
    }
    else {
        $kGrid.tbody.on('mousedown', function (e) {
            showConfirmation(e);
        });
    }
};

function showConfirmation(e) {
    var dialogResult = confirm("confirm?");
        if (dialogResult) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So, issue is when dialogResult is false, the immediate propagation is stopped as expected but when the dialog result is true.. the underlying kendo event is not getting fired.

I've also tried using kgrid.trigger("change"); but that doesnt work either. So, is there a way to resolve this problem or anyhow reset stopImmediatePropagation so that kendo change event is fired when dialogResult is true?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

*Not really an answer but too long for a comment*

Are you sure that it's `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`, called on the `mousedown` event, that inhibits the underlying Kendo event? I strikes me that the inhibition may be caused by something else, possibly display of the confirm dialog itself, regardless of its outcome.

If so, then you may need to consider a completely differnt strategy.

It is more normal to put a confirmation in the same event thread as the code it allows/suppresses, rather than getting statements in one thread to suppress another event. I guess that you are trying to avoid having to hack the Kendo code but that might ultimately be the easier option.

### EDIT

The code should simplify as follows :

```
$.fn.extendedFunction= function () {
    var $grid = $(this);
    var $kGrid = $grid.data("kendoGrid");
    if ($kGrid) {
        $kGrid.tbody.on('mousedown', function (e) {
            if (!confirm("Confirm?")) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        });
    }
    return this;
};
```

If, as you say below, `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` is indeed the inhibiting statement, then the simpler code might just work.

Comment: Hi, yes..I'm pretty sure that e.stopImmediatePropagation() is inhibiting the underlying kemdo event. When I comment that code, then irrespective of the confirm dialog the change event on the Kendo grid is fired when grid row selection is changed.

Comment: But you say in the question that "when the dialog result is true.. the underlying kendo event is not getting fired". Something doesn't add up.

Comment: Thats right, at first parse before e.stopImmediatePropagation is hit, the kendo event is fired when dialog result is true. But once dislog result is false & e.stopImmediatePropagation is hit then next time when I try to change a kendo row selection then dialog is shown & even if the dialog result is true this time, the underlying kendo event is not fired. That happens only after e.stopImmediatePropagation was hit at least once.

Comment: I'll try the above simplified code & will let you know. thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I working in a horror "framework" this time, and I cant use any differnt strategy, like this (just a very dumb example, but working):

```
let stop = true;
$('#something').on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (stop) {
        ev.stopImmediatePropagation();

        // Why you want this? Here you can do tests, or whatever...

        // if those are success:
        stop = false;
        $('#something').click();
    }

    // do your stuff ...
```

May help ...